# Why isn't my `KubernetesPodOperator` using the IRSA I've annotated worker pods with?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, airflow, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I've deployed an EKS cluster using the Terraform module `terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws`. I’ve deployed Airflow on this EKS cluster with Helm (the official chart, not the community one), and I’ve annotated worker pods with the following IRSA:

```yaml
  serviceAccount:
    # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
    create: true
    # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
    # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the release name
    name: "airflow-worker"

    # Annotations to add to worker kubernetes service account.
    annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/airflow-worker"
```

This `airflow-worker` role has a policy attached to it to enable it to assume a different role.

I have a Python program that assumes this other role and performs some S3 operations.  I can `exec` into a running `BashOperator` pod, open a Python shell, assume this role, and issue the exact same S3 operations successfully.

But, when I create a Docker image with this program and try to call it from a `KubernetesPodOperator` task, I see the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: 
User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/core_node_group-eks-node-group-20220726041042973200000001/i-089c64b96cf7878d8 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::987654321:role/TheOtherRole
```

I don't really know what this role is, but I believe it was created automatically by the Terraform module.  However, when I `kubectl describe` one of these failed pods, I see this:

```
    Environment:
      ...
      ...
      ...
      AWS_ROLE_ARN: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/airflow-worker
```

My questions:

1. Why is *this* role being used, and not the IRSA `airflow-worker` that I've specified in the Helm chart's values?
2. What even is this role?  It seems the Terraform module creates a number of roles automatically, but it is very difficult to tell what their purpose is or where they're used from the Terraform documentation.
3. <s>How am I able to assume this role and do everything the Dockerized Python program does when in a shell in the pod?</s>  Okay, this is because other operators (such as `BashOperator`) *do* use the `airflow-worker` role.  Just not `KubernetesPodOperator`s.
4. What is the `AWS_IAM_ROLE` environment variable, and why isn't *it* being used?

Happy to provide more context if it's helpful.

Comment: you can verify the role token inside pods `/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount` and when you run this command `aws sts get-caller-identity` you will see which role is being used by pod

Comment: every node come with default role, `core_node_group-eks...` this seems default role for the worker node.

Comment: >but it is very difficult to tell what their purpose is or where they're .....
this is how node talk with AWS service and create load balancer etc when install nginx ingress

Comment: @Adiii Yes, I know that it's using the `core_node_group-eks-node-group` role.  That much is evident from the error message.  My question is, why?  If I run a `BashOperator` task that just sleeps for an hour, open a Python shell, and do a `boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()`, I see that it's using the `airflow-worker` role.  So, more precisely, why doesn't the worker pod annotation apply to all worker pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much by design.  The non-`KubernetesPodOperator`s use an auto-generated pod template file that has Helm chart values as default properties, while the `KubernetesPodOperator` needs its own pod template file.  That, or it needs to essentially create one by passing arguments to `KubernetesPodOperator(...`.

I fixed the ultimate issue by passing `service_account="airflow-worker"` to `KubernetesPodOperator(...`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the AWS role in EKS pod, you need to add this policy to it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": " arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/airflow-worker” 
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  }
```

[Here](https://any-api.com/amazonaws_com/sts/docs/API_Description) you can find some information about AWS Security Token Service (STS).

For the tasks running in the worker prod, they will use the role automatically, but if you create a new pod, it will be separated from your worker pod, so you need to let it use the service account which attach the role in order to add the AWS role creds file to the pod.